# How to save Firestore response, after I add a doc, in React Native (Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1): TypeError: "res" is read-only)?

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, promise

I'll try to keep it simple. I save a doc in firestore

```
const res = await firestore()
        .collection(firestoreNodeNames.BOOKINGS)
        .add(bookingObject);
```

If I simply log `res.id`, it works fine.
But if I try to save the `res` in a variable, either directly or with `setMyCustomState(res)` (for reusability),  it gives me this error

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1): TypeError: "res" is read-only
```

Is there a workaround to this?

Answer (score 1):

You declared res as a const, that is why you can't mutate it.
You can change "const" to "let" or create a mutable clone of the original obj like this:

```
let clone = Object.create(res)
```